# Complex Numbers in Cython - I or 1j?

Tags: cython

Whenever I attempt to do simple complex arithmetic in Cython, I seem to get some Python overhead; does this have anything to do with using the Pythonic `1j`? At this point, I can't find any way to import the C-style imaginary unit into Cython. Is this possible?

Take for example, the simple Cython function below that converts polar complex numbers into a rectangular form. (Note this is using cos and sin cimported from the `"complex.h"` library)

`cdef float complex rect(float r, float phi):
    return r*cos(phi) + r*sin(phi)*1j`

This code is converted into the following C code by Cython:

`__pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_c_sum(__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts((__pyx_v_r * cos(__pyx_v_phi)), 0), __Pyx_c_prod(__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts((__pyx_v_r * sin(__pyx_v_phi)), 0), __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(0, 1.0)));
  __pyx_r = __pyx_t_float_complex_from_parts(__Pyx_CREAL(__pyx_t_1), __Pyx_CIMAG(__pyx_t_1));
  goto __pyx_L0;`

Considering the simple nature of this function, it seems like this should be able to be converted into pure C yet it remains partially in the Python realm - is there something that I'm missing in order to make this statement be converted into pure C?

Comment: I think this is more to do with supporting different implementations of `complex` for C (with <complex.h>), C++ (with `std::complex`) and a DIY type without either. Hopefully the functions/macros are all fairly lightweight (but you can probably check this at the top of the generated C file).

Comment: Yeah - the actual Python code seems moderately lightweight. The question was more a matter of IF it was possible (because it seemed like it should be) as opposed to a need to remove the performance constraints of the small Python section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to use `I` from `complex.h` instead of `1j`, as in:

```
cdef extern from "complex.h":
    double cos(double x) nogil
    double sin(double x) nogil
    float complex I

def rect(r, phi):
    return crect(r, phi)

cdef float complex crect(float r, float phi):
    cdef float rpart = r*cos(phi)
    cdef float ipart = r*sin(phi)
    return rpart + ipart * I
```

`cython -a` reports no Python code for `crect`.

Comment: Simple perfect answer for a simple question. Thanks!