# Cython: using I from <complex.h> , can't get it to work

Tags: cython, complex-numbers

I am following this thread and it's well resolved:
[Complex Numbers in Cython - I or 1j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643413/complex-numbers-in-cython-i-or-1j)

However when I tried, it just doesn't seem to work. This is my fairly simple example:

```
cdef extern from "<complex.h>"  nogil:
    double cos( double x )
    double sin( double x )
    double complex I

@cython.boundscheck(False)      # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound (False)      # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
@cython.cdivision  (True )
cdef double complex c_exp_i (double z) nogil:
    return cos( z ) + sin( z ) * I
```

I get such error message:

```
error C2676: binary '*': '__pyx_t_double_complex' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

I don't see what am I doing wrong / different than the previous post. Any idea how to make it work ?
EDIT: This is more of a curiosity than an efficiency purpose.

EDIT2: Using MSVC 2017, using C++ in python setup.py file.

Comment: You should provide info about your compiler and whether it is c or c++. Complex numbers are differently supported by different compilers

Comment: oh I see. Thank you. I'll add it.